# How do I align images to be horizontal or vertical?

Tags: css, alignment

I know this has been asked before--but it's such a simple issue--that all the answers are too advanced...lol....

Anyway, I always get stuck on the simplest things. Here is the deal: I have two images on top of each other on the right side, and below that two images side-by-side.

The vertical images located on the right hand side work. However, the #tent and #twins imgs are also vertical and I need them to be horizontal. I have tried the float property but they simply stack vertically with one on the left and one on the right.

Again...this is a simple issue, I know. But I do greatly appreciate the assistance.

This is the code I have thus far:

```
#aboutUs h2{
font-size:36px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding:0 0 0 0;}

#aboutusPara{
position:absolute;
float:left;
width:30%;
line-height:40px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

#karennorm{
width:50%;
border-radius:100px;
margin-left:50%;
position:relative;}


#wagon{
width:50%;
margin-top:5%;
margin-left:50%;
border-radius:100px;}

figcaption.aboutTop{
margin-top:.5em;
margin-left:50%;
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
width:50%;}

#tent{
width:40%;
border-radius:100px;}

#twins{
width:40%;
border-radius:100px;}

section#aboutBottom{
padding:2em 0 0 0;} 


figcaption.aboutBottom1{
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
width:30%;
padding:0 0 2em 0;
margin-left:5%;}

figcaption.aboutBottom2{
margin-left:5%;
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
font-style:italic;
width:30%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the images should stack horizontally by default but maybe within your code you changed something so try this for the 2 images you want to be next to eachother horizontally.

> display:inline;

or

> display:inline-block;

if you want to keep the box model properties for the images.